# Pygame setting boundaries for screen size

Tags: python, pygame

I have my screen set using:

```
DisplayHeight = 0
DisplayWidth = 0

pygame.display.set_mode = ((DisplayWidth, DisplayHeight), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

then later when I try to set the boundaries using:

```
if imgx <= DisplayWidth:
    Right = False
    Left = False

if imgy <= DisplayHeight:
    Up = False
    Down = False
```

This leads to two problems. 1. The image only stops when I hit the left side of the screen or the top. Any other way it just keeps going.

2. When the image does stop at the spots it will stop at, if someone starts hitting the button to take them in that direction it will still go that way, except you would have to just keep mashing the button and you could go off screen that way.

I have tried finding answers to this problem, but I couldn't find any information on it.

Comment: Please post some additional information, such as the source code relevant to controlling and moving the picture. The code you have provided is out of context, and does not provide a clear picture of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your variables `DisplayHeight` and `DisplayWidth` are both set to `0`, so your code

```
if imgx <= DisplayWidth:
    Right = False
    Left = False

if imgy <= DisplayHeight:
    Up = False
    Down = False
```

just checks if `imgx` or `imgy` is smaller than `0`.

---

Also, instead of

```
pygame.display.set_mode = ((DisplayWidth, DisplayHeight), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

you probably wanted to use

```
pygame.display.set_mode((DisplayWidth, DisplayHeight), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

since `set_mode` is a function.

---

If you want to prevent a moving object from leaving the screen, consider using the [`clamp`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.clamp) or [`clamp_ip`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.clamp_ip) function:

> **clamp()**
>   *moves the rectangle inside another*
>   `clamp(Rect) -> Rect Returns`
>   a new rectangle that is moved to be completely inside the argument
>   Rect. If the rectangle is too large to fit inside, it is centered
>   inside the argument Rect, but its size is not changed.

So a single line like

```
your_rect.clamp_ip(the_rect_of_the_screen)
```

is enough to ensure `your_rect` never leaves `the_rect_of_the_screen`.

Comment: So then how would I take into account for playing on a screen on a different size than my own?

Answer (score 0):

The

```
DisplayHeight = 0
DisplayWidth = 0

pygame.display.set_mode = ((DisplayWidth, DisplayHeight), pygame.FULLSCRE
```

one always works for me in any version of python

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that may provide help for your problem. It appears that you do not have appropriate limits on the motion of the image. Be sure to have constraints like `0 <= current_pos + image_dimension +/- increment <= display_size`.

```
DisplayHeight = 500
DisplayWidth = 800

vertical_increment = 10
horizontal_increment = 10

img = pygame.image.load('image/path')
imgx = 0
imgy = 0
imgw = image.get_width()
imgh = image.get_height()

while 1:
  key = function to get key
  if key == 'up':
    if imgy - vertical_increment >= 0:
      move_image('up')
  elif key == 'down':
    if imgy + imgh + vertical_increment <= DisplayHeight:
      move_image('down')
  #corresponding code for horizontal
```

In general, when you post questions, please include more detailed source code so that other users may be able to accurately and efficiently answer your question, and guess as little as possible.

I hope this helps.